# means and grand means

Tags: t-test, mean, repeated-measures

I have 12 volunteers in group A and 12 volunteers in group B. From each volunteer I collected 5 urine samples over 5 days and determined the concentration of a metabolite. I want to report in a table values in groups A and B as mean, SD, geometric mean, 95% CI of geometric mean, and range.

I am not sure now if I should (1) enter the 60 points for each group and ask graphpad to calculate the above mentioned parameters.
Or If I should (2) calculate means for each volunteer and enter the 12 means for each group in graphpad prism instead.

I am also not sure if there is a third option that includes entering all 60 points for each group but in such a way that it deals with each 5 points as replicates for the same volunteer. Then maybe the calculations for the above parameters would yield different results than (1) and (2)?

Which of the 3 options do you think is right? And which one should be used for calculating the P value?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am wrestling with a similar problem and have yet to find an answer anywhere here.